# Convert columns in a list from character to numeric

Tags: r

I have a list with two data sets and I would like to convert each of the columns from character to numeric.

```
[[1]]
                 b                m
2 12194.0968074593 703.359790781974

[[2]]
                 b                m
2 49.2080763267713 30.9186232579308



> str(tidy_linear_regression)
List of 2
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ b: chr "12194.0968074593"
  ..$ m: chr "703.359790781974"
 $ :'data.frame':   1 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ b: chr "49.2080763267713"
  ..$ m: chr "30.9186232579308"
```

I cannot come up with a code where I end up with a list.
I tried the following code and the result is always a data.frame:

```
tidy_linear_regression_new <- 
  lapply(tidy_linear_regression, 
         function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
tidy_linear_regression_new<-
  sapply(tidy_linear_regression, 
         as.character)
```

Comment: `lapply(tidy_linear_regression, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

We may use `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
tidy_linear_regresion <- map(tidy_linear_regresion, ~ .x %>%
                mutate(across(everything(), as.numeric)))
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple columns in the dataframe you need `lapply` inside a `lapply` -

```
tidy_linear_regression <- lapply(tidy_linear_regression, function(x) {
  x[] <- lapply(x, as.numeric)
  x
})
```